# Error (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE9 des ...' for column 'title' at row 29") occured in import csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

When I try to imprt data from csv file to mysql, an OperationalError occured:

```
OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE9 des ...' for column 'title' at row 29")
```

My sql config is as below (version 5.7.22):

```
mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name                        | Value                      |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client                 | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection             | utf8                       |
| character_set_database               | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem             | binary                     |
| character_set_results                | utf8                       |
| character_set_server                 | utf8                       |
| character_set_system                 | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir                   | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1                          |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My schema is

```
"""                                                                                    
...: CREATE TABLE `Movies` (
...: `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
...: `title` varchar(255) default '',
...: `genres` varchar(255) default '',
...: primary key(`id`)) engine=innodb charset=utf8mb4"""
```

The csv file is the movies.csv downloaded from [ml-latest-small.zip](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip) .
To read the csv file, one function is written:

```
def import_data(tablename, filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        keys = next(reader)
        keys[0] = 'id'   # change `movieId` in csv to `id`.
        database.insertmany(tablename, keys, reader)
```

When I run import_data('Movies', 'movies.csv'), the error occured:

```
OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE9 des ...' for column 'title' at row 29")
```

I checked row 29 in the movies.csv, accordingly:

```
movieId,title,genres
30,Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao) (1995),Crime|Drama
```

I Couldn't figure out the reason. Anyone having any ideas for this issue? Many thanks~

Comment: Have you tried to find the line with '\\xE9 des ...' in the movies.csv?
The line you provided doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, man. The fact is that after I restarted my virtual machine, everything somehow turned out to be okay. So I guess the error was caused by my VM.